# Page Flashing after load in Chrome and Mozilla, but not in Opera and Edge

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

I am working on website https://www.designersheds.com.au and it has strange flashing after a page loaded. It shows correctly and then blinks. This behavior occurs in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Opera and Edge (although in Edge some styles don't seem right). All scripts are in the footer. And all styles are in head (I use Autoptimize Plugin for WordPress).

This flashing is occurring on the staging website before any optimization done.

The website is on WordPress with Genesis Child theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a behaviour is the consequence of moving all styles and fonts to the footer. I assume you tried to follow PageSpeed recommendations :). Not all of them are acceptable for each and every site.

Browser doesn't know about your styles at the moment when it starts to create DOM. It generates and outputs the whole page and then encounters some styles in footer. Application of your styles causes the whole DOM to be rebuilt what causes page blinks.

What to do?

1st method. Implement only those recommendation of PageSpeed, which do not corrupt your site. All in all - what is your goal? To make a **working** site which is as fast as possible. And moving critical styles to the header will not slower your site too much.

2nd method. Place critical styles in header as inline code. In this case, PageSpeed will not decrease scores. But this approach demands a kind of manual work and cannot be done with Autoptimize.

Comment: "cannot be done with Autoptimize"; except that it can; when "inline & defer" is active you'll see a textarea in which one can enter the critical css :)

frank (ao dev)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right about PageSpeed optimization. But the problem is that AO style is in the head the first thing that is loading (my client didn't link the unstyled content flashing when I used "inline & defer"). And this flashing is occurring on the staging website before any optimization done. You can see it here http://staging.finicky-brush.flywheelsites.com/ login: flywheel pass:envious-sheep

Comment: And the person who downvoted the question, could you please tell the reason?

Comment: @futtta Wow! futtta is with us! Sorry, I overlooked this opportunity in your plugin and take my words back. And thank you for the great plugin!

Comment: @KAGGDesign, I didn't mean that it was you. I just commented for the person who did to explain the reason in comments, like I saw in the other questions. Thank you for your reply on my question. Could you please review my comment with other details and tell what do you think?

Comment: @futtta I agree with KAGGDesign - your plugin is awesome for speed optimization. Thank you for great work!

Comment: What I was able find so far: if we look at Performance tab in Chrome http://take.ms/5XKwSR, we can find that screen becomes white when Google Tag Manager script starts. I have no idea at this moment why, but try to switch it off on staging site and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you @KAGGDesign, you helped a lot. It was really a GTM. I investigated that some of the tags (custom HTML) caused this flashing. Ater putting them in the head manually and removing from GTM everything works fine. Thank you again!